# Referencing keywords from another robot file

Tags: robotframework

I have a resource.robot file where i want to keep my keywords here.

## resource.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Process

*** Keywords ***
Start Server 
        ${result}=  Run Process  python  script.py
```

Another robot file where i want to reference the keyword "Start Server" to run the process as shown below.

## test.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Resource          resource.robot

*** Test cases ***
Run Server
    resource.Start Server  #Keyword from resource.robot file
```

But my error is that i **cannot find the keyword 'Start Server'** when i run test.robot. Been trying out the different post available here but still cannot resolve this problem.

Would appreciate if anyone have any idea about this situation.

Comment: Is both files are in same package?

Comment: hi @Dev, they are all in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find out what's the issue.

I added in Test Cases section for my resource.robot file thinking that it will not affect the resource.robot file.

After pouring through the documentation, i realized that the test cases section is the issue.

**Removing the test cases section for my resource.robot file solved the problem.**

> The higher-level structure of resource files is the same as that of
>   test case files otherwise, but, of course, they cannot contain Test
>   Case tables. Additionally, the Setting table in resource files can
>   contain only import settings (Library, Resource, Variables) and
>   Documentation. The Variable table and Keyword table are used exactly
>   the same way as in test case files.

Referenced to: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-user-keywords